# Connect to Entity Framework Core in .NET 3.1 Azure Function Project Startup.cs

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I am attempting to use entity framework against a database in Azure. I have a connection string stored in the local.settings.json, but all of my attempts to reference it from a Startup.cs have failed.

I am able to access my connection string using an IConfiguration DI into a function class and I can successfully access the database with SQL Command using the configuration like:

```
string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("cpni");
```

So I know that the connection string is working and that I can access it.

If I try to use DI with IConfiguration on the **Startup class**, the compiler does not give me any errors, but once it's running in debug I begin getting the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'CPNI_Functions.Startup'.

Here is what I'm currently successfully using with a **hardcoded** connectionString (since using DI with IConfiguration isn't working):

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CpniContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And that allows me to work with the database through EF. What I would like to use is some combination of that and something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CpniContext>(/*options need to go here?*/)
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((configuration) =>
    {
        //Or are options supposed to go here somewhere, or be bound here with some sort of .Bind()?
        configuration.GetConnectionString("cpni");
    });
```

If that doesn't make sense or won't work, then please let me know what the recommended way of setting this DI up is. If possible, I want to avoid using configuration lookup through ConfigurationManager.

For reference, here is the full Startup.cs and this works:

```
using CPNI_Functions.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(CPNI_Functions.Startup))]

namespace CPNI_Functions
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = "myconnectionstringhere";

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CpniContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
        /*
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CpniContext>(configuration.GetConnectionString("cpni"));
        }*/
    }
}
```

I'm new to core and I'm new to Azure Functions, so please forgive my ignorance on this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For an Azure function app you could try adding NuGet package:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "cpni": "[ConnectionStringDetails]"
  }
}
```

Then hopefully you should be able to access using ConfigurationManager.

```
services.AddDbContext<CpniContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cpni"].ConnectionString));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however that doesn't answer my problem. My problem is that I cannot gain access to the Configuration object that you are using in your action. Can you detail how you are doing that? Direct Injection in the Startup class isn't working for me as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Have updated for when using Azure Function App, previous answer was for a web API project. Hopefully better!

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure that works, however I do wish to avoid configuration manager if at all possible. IConfiguration is part of Function apps and I wish to get a working version using that.

Comment: @StevenC did you solve this problem ever? If so, what was the solution?

Comment: @SriReddy Unfortunately I never did find a solution to this problem.